# Should my function return False if it has to return a boolean value?

Tags: python, boolean, nonetype

What are the benefits of writing:

```
def contains(lst, n):
  for x in lst:
    if x == n:
      return True
  return False
```

instead of:

```
def contains(lst, n):
  for x in lst:
    if x == n:
      return True
```

?

Please note that in the second example the last line of code is missing, and the function returns `None` instead of `False`.

*Side note*: I'm aware I should write `n in lst`, this is just an example.

Comment: It's worth noting that in most such real-life examples, where you can't just `return n in lst`, you can still `return any(n *** x for x in lst)`, where `n *** x` is whatever expression you need to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It really depends on how you intend the function to be used.

If it's only ever going to be used in a boolean context, it might make sense to define and document it as "returns something truthy or something falsey", in which case it's reasonable to return `None` as something falsey.

But if you expect people to, say, log the result for human debugging purposes, or use it as a key in a dictionary—or you just don't know how it's going to be used—it's a lot clearer to say it returns a boolean and then explicitly return `False`.

In fact, it's often a nice idea to be stricter than you promise in what you provide; even if you only document that you're returning something truthy or falsey, it won't actually *hurt* to always return `True` or `False`, unless you have some other value that could be meaningful.* As the other answers imply, this doesn't just go along with general programming principles, but also the specific Python Zen "explicit is better than implicit".

<sub>* If you're thinking that it could hurt performance, it won't, even if that were an issue. An implicit `return None` complies to exactly the same `LOAD_CONST` and `RETURN_VALUE` as an explicit `return None`—or, of course, an explicit `return False`.</sub>

Comment: It also helps to make your intention clear to the reader of the code. A missing return statement might make the reader ask themselves, "Did they author forget to return something? Should I put in a return statement here to fix the code?" and so on. Minimizing such concerns makes the code much easier to read.

Comment: @kqr: Good point. Implementation may not be as important as interface, but it's still important—especially in Python, where people may be apt to say "the code is the documentation" than in less-readable languages…

Answer (score 6):

I think to some extent this is a matter of personal preference.

I personally would always prefer former over the latter, since ["explicit is better than implicit"](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/).

Also, if the function is expected to return a `bool`, I think it's cleaner to return a `bool` and not some other object whose truthiness needs to be evaluated in order to get a `bool`.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't explicitly return anything, the return value will be `None`. If the function should return a boolean value, you really should explicitly return `False`.

In your case, `None` will evaluate to `False` when implicitly converted to `bool`, but I wouldn't depend on such behavior. Basically just to be explicit and to improve readability.

Answer (score 0):

But it is not entirely about readability. Using a function that is supposed to return a boolean but does not, can lead to faulty behaviour when the value is explicitly compared:

```
def contains(lst, n):
  for x in lst:
    if x == n:
      return True
l=[1,2]
i=3
if(contains(l,i)==False):
  print ("{} is not found in list {}".format(i,str(l)))
else:
  print ("{} is found in list {}".format(i,str(l)))
```

The output of this snippet will be:
`3 is found in list [1, 2]`